# What is the significance of power set of $\phi$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The formula of subsets of any sets is : $2^n$

We have a subset of $\phi$ because $2^0 = 1$ and the subset is $\phi$
itself.

Therefore:

$p(\phi) = \{{ \phi}\}$

$p(p(\phi) = \{{ \phi, \{\phi\}}\}$

$p(p(p(\phi)) = \{{ \phi, \{\phi\}, \{\phi ,\{\phi\} \},  \{ \{ \phi \}\}}\}$

And so it goes on... but what is the mathematical significance of the above power sets?

Comment: Don't use \phi for the empty set(!), that confused me. Use \emptyset, $\emptyset$, or \varnothing, $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is the empty set. The set whose only element is the empty set is $1.$ For more, google "von Neumann ordinals".